# Reverse proxy from Nginx to Dockerized Wordpress is causing an infinite redirect loop

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

My Wordpress website should appear at `http://192.168.122.50/blog/`

I started out by creating this server block

```
server {
  server_name 192.168.122.50;
  listen 80;

  location /blog/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000; # My Wordpress site
  }
}
```

Next, I added the two following lines to my Wordpress config (wp-config.php):

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://192.168.122.50/blog/' );                                                                                  
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://192.168.122.50/blog/' );
```

I keep getting infinite redirect loops to this URL: `http://192.168.122.50/blog/wp-admin/install.php`

Here is the HTTP response I receive, according to httpie:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 07 Apr 2019 15:13:50 GMT
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Location: http://192.168.122.50/blog/wp-admin/install.php
Server: nginx/1.12.2
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.17
X-Redirect-By: WordPress
```

I have attempted to fix this issue by adding the following lines after the proxy_pass, but to no avail.

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Also, I am using the `wordpress:latest` Docker image.

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress uses apache web server internally to route request so i am assuming you are puting nginx on top of wp-apache stack.

you should able to do this by sending every request coming to nginx proxy passing to apache by simply using below block

```
server {
  server_name _;
  listen 80;
    location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
}
```